# Hide extra images in gallery slideshow

Tags: html, css, image, carousel, gallery

I'm trying to partially hide these images. In this example you can see that the "four" and "five" images are exceeding the list so i need to hide the parts that shouldn't be visible.

Here is what is happening:
[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Finisterix/pen/RwjqKzj)

And here is what i'm trying to do: [image]

HTML code:

```
<div class="gallery-row">
  <ul class="list">
    <div class="list__item">
      <img class="list__thumbnail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg/1024px-NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg.png">
    </div>
    //and four more images below
  </ul>
</div>
```

SASS code:

```
.gallery-row {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  .list {
      display: flex;
      gap: 20px;
      list-style: none;
      width: 100%;
      .list__item {
        min-width: 220px;
        height: 220px;
        .list__thumbnail {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation i could find a solution just adding `overflow: hidden` in "gallery-row" div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your .gallery-row.

```
overflow : hidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an overflow of hidden to your `.gallery-row` class.

```
.gallery-row {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  .list {
      display: flex;
      gap: 20px;
      list-style: none;
      width: 100%;
      .list__item {
        min-width: 220px;
        height: 220px;
        .list__thumbnail {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Here is a simpler implementation for the same effect

```
<div class="row">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg/1024px-NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg.png">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Icon_2_%28set_basic%29.png"> 
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/ba/NYCS-bull-trans-4-red.svg/2048px-NYCS-bull-trans-4-red.svg.png"> 
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg/1024px-NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg.png">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/Channel_5_logo_2011.svg/1024px-Channel_5_logo_2011.svg.png">
</div>
```

```
.row {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.25rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row img {
  min-width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gallery-row {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  .list {
      display: flex;
      gap: 20px;
      list-style: none;
      width: 100%;
      .list__item {
        min-width: 220px;
        height: 220px;
        .list__thumbnail {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-row">
  <ul class="list">
    <div class="list__item">
      <img class="list__thumbnail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg/1024px-NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="list__item">
      <img class="list__thumbnail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Icon_2_%28set_basic%29.png"> 
    </div>
    <div class="list__item">
      <img class="list__thumbnail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/NYCS-bull-trans-3.svg/1200px-NYCS-bull-trans-3.svg.png"> 
    </div>
    <div class="list__item">
      <img class="list__thumbnail" style="visibility: hidden;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/ba/NYCS-bull-trans-4-red.svg/2048px-NYCS-bull-trans-4-red.svg.png">  
    </div>
    <div class="list__item">
      <img class="list__thumbnail" style="visibility: hidden;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/Channel_5_logo_2011.svg/1024px-Channel_5_logo_2011.svg.png"> 
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).